# Windows 10 IoT 10.0.14393.953 update issues

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I have an issue with the Windows 10 IoT version 10.0.14393.953.
I developped my custom home automation app this one crashed last night at 3:09 AM (according to my logs). And I saw that an update was completed at 3:19 AM...
Since that the device portal shows no process and no app.

See the following screenshot of the device portal:
[image: Device portal shows no app and I am unable to restart my app]

And there is no information in the device portal:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What's dashboard? [Windows iot core dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/iotdashboard) surely can't show any process and apps.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the web interface provided by Windows 10 (the Windows Device Portal)

Comment: So, currently you have the version 14393.953? Do you mean the update caused your app crash? I am not clear what's exactly your issue?

Comment: Yes I mean the app crashed has been cause by the update. But the problem is not the crash of my app, but it is that I am unable to restart it because the device portal displays no app and no process. I will update my first post with captures of the device portal

Comment: Have you tried using command:[IotStartup list](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/commandlineutils)? Can you see your app and other apps? What about Processes, Performance, etc, behave normally in the device portal?

Comment: I will test it tonight and give you a feedback. The processes list is also empty in the device portal. About Performance, there is no information (see my update in the first post)

Comment: Okay, so I tried to list apps from a remote PowerShell and all the basic apps are listed. And my app is listed too.

Comment: Have your tried reboot the device?

Comment: Yes, I restarted it several times. Do you have feedback from other users about this version of Windows 10 IoT?

Comment: I use 14393.953 and it has not such problem. Maybe there was something happened during the update process. To solve this issue you can reflash the 14393.953 version using [iot dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/iotdashboard).

Comment: It seems the issue appears only when I access the rpi from an external network. In this case, the list of installed apps is empty. But if I access it from the same network (local network) then everything works well.